# If I click the button, is there a way to see the accordion menu calculated in height?

Tags: javascript

I have a question.
When I click on a specific text button, I want to make the accordion box automatically calculated in height visible.
Now, the accordion box itself works in a way that clicks like a giant button, not a specific text button.

I want to modify the code that the 'active' class will add when the 'text button' is clicked, rather than the 'accordion box' is clicked.
I don't know how. I need your help.
Thank you!

[TEST WEBSITE](https://statement00.cafe24.com/stmtwp/?product=test)

```js
if (matchMedia("all and (max-width: 812px)").matches) {

} else {
  var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("info-box");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      var panel = this;
      if (panel.style.height) {
        panel.style.height = null;
      } else {
        panel.style.height = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.info-box {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 62px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: height 0.3s;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 99;
}

.shopbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1.4px;
  z-index: 9999999999;
  bottom: 12px;
  left: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="info-box" style>
  <div class="shopbtn">Information</div>

  test test test
</div>
```

Comment: The snippet is not working please remove the `<script>` tags from the javascript part

Comment: use `elem.getBoundingClientRect()` to get the dimensions of accordion. `elem` is the element you want to get the height of.